# Problems linking to Windows APIs in VS 2012 Express for Desktop in C#

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm new to Windows desktop programming (or at least I haven't done it since, um, Windows 3.0).  I've got VS 2012 Express for Desktop installed. I have a default forms-based project created and running. Now I'd like to add in a Windows API with the following lines [per pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetLayeredWindowAttributes):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
```

I'm getting two errors for this code:

1. The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item (on the closing square bracket of the attribute)
2. Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct (on `bool`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you specify this? It should be placed in a class definition.

Comment: @CodeCaster -- ah, duh, that's it, thanks. I didn't put it in a class. Inside a class it works, of course.

Comment: This is not appropriate in a Winforms app.  Instead use the Form.TransparencyKey and Opacity properties, you'll get the internal call to SetLayeredWindowAttributes() for free.  Use the Region property for shape.

Comment: @HansPassant -- ok, it did feel strange to be hooking in those Windows APIs given all the newer classes. I'm guessing there are similar wrappers using WPF if I end up doing it with WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're placing this declaration within a class definition, not outside it.

Typically, you'd keep P/Invokes within a static class called `NativeMethods`, which you then invoke using a call like `NativeMethods.SetLayeredWindowedAttributes(...)`. For example:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
}
```

If you want to call it without a type reference, then you need to put it in the same class as you're calling it in, but unless you're sure you won't use this P/Invoke anywhere else, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the `NativeMethods` tip also!

Answer (score 1):

Because you must encapsulate this code on class

```
class MainClass 
{
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
   .....

}
```